# Vue count string length

Tags: javascript, vue.js, string-length

**VIEW**

```
<div v-for="(listings, index) in list4" :key="index">
   <input v-model="listings.rfidState2" type="text"/>
</div>

<div v-for="(element2, index) in list4" :key="index">
  <p v-if="list4[index].rfidState2 > 0">WORKING</p>
</div>
```

If I insert value as AC87SG67A for an input field it throws me an error at `v-if="list4[index].rfidState2 > 0"` but if I insert the value as 98292001 it displays **WORKING**. Is there a way to display **WORKING** for any value inserted such as integer or alphabet(a to z) inside `<input v-model="listings.rfidState2" type="text"/>` textfield ?

Comment: `v-if="list4[index].rfidState2.length > 0` ?

Comment: I guess it throws there is no definition if this literal and not a number is larger than any number?

Comment: 'AC87SG67A' is alpha numeric while `98292001` that is why you can compare it against 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can add a [`.trim`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#trim) modifier to the input like:

```
<input v-model.trim="listings.rfidState2" type="text"/>
```

Now, any whitespace from user input to be trimmed automatically. Next, we can simply check if any text was entered or not like:

```
<p v-if="list4[index].rfidState2.length">WORKING</p>
```

So, if any integer or alphabet is entered then `length` will return a value greater than 0, which is *truthy* and thus the `v-if` will show the element, else it will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

`list4[index].rfidState2` is a string. You cannot compare it with a number. If you do so, JavaScript will do the implicit type conversion, and the result will not make sense. `list4[index].rfidState2.length` is the actual length of the string. So, what you should write is "`list4[index].rfidState2.length > 0`"